# Padding oracle attack, encrypting your own message

Tags: encryption, cryptography, padding-oracle-attack

My understanding of the encryption attack on a padding oracle is that the attacker has a set of Pi's and Dec(Ci)'s

I understand that by back calculating the attacker can find out Ci-1's because we have

```
Pi = Dec(Ci) ^ Ci-1
```

This way the attacker can find all the Ci-1's, but what happens with the first Ci? Since you're starting from the end and going backwards, it looks like the very last Ci wont get calculated, in which case the attacker isn't able to encrypt all of the message...?

Comment: PKCS#7 padding is always performed, up to a full block of padding.

Comment: ok so let me see if i get this correctly, you add a full block of just padding, and go backwards like that? correct?

Comment: actually that doesn't make any sense, how does padding help you find the last cipher block? what we need is an extra decipher block Dec(Ci+1) so that we can find Ci..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming. The better forum is crypto.stackexchange.com.